# procedurally animating a little ascii man's speech using text input

Tags: animation, ascii, procedural-generation

I'm taking a course called "Documenting and Developing Technology," and in this course, we're supposed to independently create wacky stuff with computers and then document using a video presentation on youtube. I've developed a gimmick that involves a small ASCII man that narrates the project instead of a human. He looks like this:

```
___  ___
 .  | .
     \
   .-_)
.______,
```

Maurice ^

I'd like him to move his mouth for the narration, but doing this by hand is extremely taxing and imprecise. I've seen plenty of videos of people turning different data formats into ASCII animations, but none of them go in-depth enough to explain how to do something like this, or how to get started. So I'm asking friendly strangers on the internet if they can point me in the right direction.

How should I go about making Maurice talk?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't have code. I suppose this question is better suited for Reddit, but I'm looking for ways to begin, not for a solution.